# Is there a limit to the number of parameters one can add to DbCommand?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Or, how many times can I call AddParameter on the ParameterCollection object in System.Data.DbCommand?

Comment: I wouldn't know of any limit besides the amount of RAM and how many parameters your SQL Server can handle - but I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this article by [Joe Celko on Simple-Talk](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/values%28%29-and-long-parameter-lists/), SQL Server can take up to 2100 parameters. It's a recent article, I'd guess it's good for SQL 2008.

Comment: +1.  Another source, although it only specifcally talks about SPs and UDFs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx.

Comment: Presumably this is also dependent on which implementation of the IDBCommand you are using, SqlCommand being one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a collection indexed by an `Int32` (`DbParameterCollection`), it would be limited by [`Int32.MaxValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue.aspx), which is 2,147,483,647.